# How can I trigger an email from this php script?

Tags: php, forms

I'm new to php and I'm trying to work out how to send myself an email upon successful payment. How would I go about that? If you see half way down the script there is an 'if' statement that defines a successful Stripe Payment Call - so that is the point where an email ought to be sent.

Do I include a POST Email request - like this:

```
($_POST['email'])) {

$email_to = "me@example.com";
$email_subject = "Email subject line";
```

And here's the php script that currently works - you'll see the 'IF' statement half way throught the script.

```
<?php
require('config.inc.php');
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$email=$_POST['email'];
// Stores errors:
$errors = array();
// Need a payment token:
if (isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Check for a duplicate submission, just in case:
// Uses sessions, you could use a cookie instead.
if (isset($_SESSION['token']) && ($_SESSION['token'] == $token)) {
  $errors['token'] = 'You have apparently resubmitted the form.';
} else { // New submission.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}   

} else {
$errors['token'] = 'Your subscription cannot be processed because you   must have JavaScript enabled. Please try again.';
}

// Set the order amount somehow:
$amount = 2700; // $20, in cents

// Validate other form data!

// If no errors, process the order:
if (empty($errors)) {

// create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {

  // Include the Stripe library:
  require_once('lib/Stripe.php');

  // set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
  // see your keys here https://manage.stripe.com/account
  Stripe::setApiKey(STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY);
  // Charge the order:
  $charge=Stripe_Customer::create(array(
  "card"=>$token,
  "email" => $email,
  "plan" =>"newsletter",
  ));
  // Check that it was paid:
  if (!empty($charge)) {
    //echo $amount;
    // Store the order in the database.
    // Send the email.
    // Celebrate!
    /*$cookie_name = "success_msg";
    $cookie_value = "Your Payment is successfully done";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");*/
    $_SESSION['success_msg']="Your subcription was successfull - thank you!<br><br>We will send you further details shortly on how to access your account.";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>";
    exit(0);

  } else { // Charge was not paid!

    echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><h4>Payment System Error!</h4>Your payment could NOT be processed (i.e., you have not been charged) because the payment system rejected the transaction. You can try again or use another card.</div>';
  }

} catch (Stripe_CardError $e) {
    // Card was declined.
  $e_json = $e->getJsonBody();
  $err = $e_json['error'];
  $errors['stripe'] = $err['message'];
} catch (Stripe_ApiConnectionError $e) {
    // Network problem, perhaps try again.
} catch (Stripe_InvalidRequestError $e) {
    // You screwed up in your programming. Shouldn't happen!
} catch (Stripe_ApiError $e) {
    // Stripe's servers are down!
} catch (Stripe_CardError $e) {
    // Something else that's not the customer's fault.
}

} // A user form submission error occurred, handled below.

} // Form submission.
?>
```

asdasd

Comment: put inside if (!empty($charge)) { to send email saying payment was sucessful etc ..

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function that sends the email:

```
function sendEmail () {
  $email_to = "me@example.com";
  $email_subject = "Email subject line";
  ... ETC ...
}
```

Then in your script where the payment is successful, just before notifying the user you can include the function:

```
...
if (!empty($charge)) {
    ...

    // Include your function if you wrote this to an external script
    require_once '/path/to/php/sendEmail.function.php';
    // Then make use of it:
    sendEmail();

    /*$cookie_name = "success_msg";
    $cookie_value = "Your Payment is successfully done";
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");*/
    $_SESSION['success_msg']="Your subcription was successfull - thank you!<br><br>We will send you further details shortly on how to access your account.";

    // Redirect the user to a new page
    echo "<script>window.location.href='index.php'</script>";

    // Then you can exit runtime
    exit(0);
}
// Charge was not paid!
else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><h4>Payment System Error!</h4>Your payment could NOT be processed (i.e., you have not been charged) because the payment system rejected the transaction. You can try again or use another card.</div>';
}
...
```

It's pretty important that the email function will either send the email or just continue as normal as you'd not want a failed email to interupt the users experience. You could have a fallback so that if the email doesnt send it writes it to the database or something but do not exit with an error during this process.